# Remote access to Java Swing application screen with interaction

Tags: java, ios, swing

Does anyone know if there's a way to provide remote access from a client to a Swing application running on a server? This question also involves how to redirect the screen output on the remote server to a file or process, as it may be a headless environment.

What I want roughly is this:

- the user on the client starts up an application on the server
- the application's screen output is routed to 'something' which sends it over to the client
- the user on the client can tap on the screen indicating mouse clicks and can optionally bring up a keyboard for keyboard input (obviously keyboard will only work if the user previously focused something on the remote app

(I'm especially interested in doing this using iOS as client platform.)

Comment: There are ways, yes; TightVNC for instance. In fact there are many ways, you should google for one which will suit you.

Comment: I am looking for something I could integrate into my app, that's the problem :)